# How do I make my ImageView scrollable without affecting the rest of the view?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimageview, uiimage

How Do I add multipleImages for the top part and have it scrollable without moving the rest of the content? Also, how do I have the little dots at the bottom to indicate which image I'm on? My code for the image is down below.
[image]

import SDWebImage

```
@IBOutlet weak var headerImage: UIImageView!


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)


    let imageUrl:NSURL? = NSURL(string: headerPhoto!)

    if let url = imageUrl {
        headerImage.sd_setImage(with: url as URL!)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for something called image slide show or image slider.

Instead of creating them by yourself which requires lots of effort, here is a [GitHub library](https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow) that is easy to use.

Basicly the way slider works is that it is a horizontal scroll view and each cell in the scroll view is an image so that you can scroll. Then, put a fixed page index element on the bottom of the scroll view to tell you which image you are currently at.

To use it, create a UIView in your viewcontroller and set both class and module to `ImageSlideshow`. Then connect  it to your ViewController.swift as IBOutLet.

Then create an array of image urls

```
let alamofireSource = [AlamofireSource(urlString: "imgurl1")!, AlamofireSource(urlString: "imgurl2")!, AlamofireSource(urlString: "imgurl3")!]
```

And finally in your `viewDidLoad()` function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    slideshow.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    slideshow.slideshowInterval = 5.0
    slideshow.pageControlPosition = PageControlPosition.underScrollView
    slideshow.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
    slideshow.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
    slideshow.contentScaleMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill

    slideshow.setImageInputs(alamofireSource)
}
```

Comment: im still confused on how to implement it in my case

Comment: @Riccardo Are you using a storyboard? Is this image slider on a view controller from storyboard?

Comment: Im using a storyboard

Comment: @Riccardo Updated answer